# How to convert a Date timestamp to mm/dd/yyyy in Js/Angular

Tags: angular

I'm using angular 14. I've an object where key-value is this:

```
processStartDate: Date Wed May 10 2023 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

I want to convert that timestamp to just 'mm/dd/yyyy'.

I tried this:

```
finalStartDate: new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(new Date(this.processStartDate));
```

But it says: "Cannot find name 'SimpleDateFormat'.ts(2304)". Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can create this custom function in a common file and access it wherever you want.

```
export function formatDate(date: Date): string {
    if (isNaN(date.getTime())) {
        return '';
    } else {
        const month = date.getMonth() + 1;
        const day = date.getDate();
        const year = date.getFullYear();
        return ('00' + month).slice(-2) + '/' + ('00' + day).slice(-2) + '/' + year;
    }
}


finalStartDate = formatDate(new Date(this.processStartDate));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
date.toLocaleDateString('en-US', {month:'2-digit', day: '2-digit',
year:'numeric'});
```

You might have to register the Locale like this:

```js
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import localeEn from '@angular/common/locales/en';
import localeEnExtra from '@angular/common/locales/extra/en';
registerLocaleData(localeEn, 'en-US', localeEnExtra);
```

[Source .toLocaleDateString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)